# What is the java equivalence to the C#-DateTime?

Tags: c#, java, datetime, equivalence

I have this function below.

It recieves a string and a key made out of another string.

The function takes the `inputs` and adds on the date to make the exact same key to validate.

```
public bool isSecureKeyCorrect(string inputs,string thatKey)
{
     DateTime now = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(2);  

     string currentDateString = (now.ToString("yyyyMMddHH"));
     string year= currentDateString.Substring(0, 4);
     string month = currentDateString.Substring(4, 2);
     string day = currentDateString.Substring(6, 2);
     string hour = currentDateString.Substring(8, 2);

     string thisKey;



     thisKey = inputs.Substring(0, 2) + month+ hour + 
     inputs.Substring(inputs.Length - 2, 2) + year + day;

     if (thisKey == thatKey)
     {
         return true;
     }
     else
         return false;


}
```

Now, since i'm a complete newb at java, and i need to make an equivalent to this function in java aswell, and i have very little knowledge about how `Date` or `DateTime` works in java, i'll be very happy if someone could give me some pointers how to properly adjust the code.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This question can be answered with just a cursory look in the Java documentation. Why do you expect us to do that for you?

Comment: @sven I was asking for pointers, not for a complete answer. I did not expect a total answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lookup the methods in GregorianCalendar: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html (Do read the detailed usage examples in the description)

Comment: Thankyou! Highly appreciated, i was looking for something like this.

Comment: Hi, I am myself learning Java and I am finding the "Head First Java" book (http://www.amazon.com/Head-First-Java-Kathy-Sierra/dp/0596009208/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1311763851&sr=8-1) very helpful and instructive. You might want to check it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Date;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

private String getDateTime() {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();
    return dateFormat.format(date);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [Joda-time's](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html).